# How to install proprietary drivers for Radeon R3 Graphics

Tags: debian, radeon, steam

I'm trying to run Steam on Debian but I'm having trouble finding what drivers I need for my laptop.

lspci | grep Graphics

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R3 Graphics] (rev 40)
```

When I run Steam:

```
Running Steam on debian 9 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

How do I get these 'radeonsi' drivers

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question. But your error had nothing to do with your driver. The Problem ist, that steam bring some own libaries within, but they are to old for the system. the package ist build for ubuntu12.04. `find ~/.steam/root/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" \) -print -delete` This deletes the old libaries from steam in your $HOME, so steam use them from your System.

Comment: P.S you have to do this after everey steam-update.